# Or condition Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to so some type of set of file extension types instead of all of the redundant OR conditions?

```
for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx") or file.endswith(".xls") or file.endswith(".xlsm") or file.endswith(".xlsb"):
```

So something like

```
if file.endswith(".xlsx","xls","xlsm","xlsb"):
```

Comment: You were close: `file.endswith((".xlsx","xls","xlsm","xlsb")):`

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) (**emphasis** mine):

> `str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if the string ends
>   with the specified suffix, otherwise return `False`. **suffix can also be
>   a tuple of suffixes to look for**. With optional start, test beginning
>   at that position. With optional end, stop comparing at that position.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Accept tuples as suffix.

So correct usage will be:

```
for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
    if file.endswith((".xlsx","xls","xlsm","xlsb")):
        pass  # do something
```

Comment: I cant accept your answer yet, but i will. Thank you